# Munin - get Nginx requests statistics by endpoint

Tags: nginx, munin

I'm running Munin on my server (currently still in development mode). I see the Nginx stats, for example:

[image: Nginx requests - by day]

I was wondering if there is a way to see the stats divided to endpoints?
For example, the amount of api.myserver.com/user/create requests vs. api.myserver.com/car/create? And if the answer yes, how to check average time of request per endpoint?

Thanks.